# Add a starting and ending point for multiplication timetable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

For example - display the 4 times table starting at 5 (4*5) and ending at 9.

```
- 4*5 = 20
- 4*6 = 24
- 4*7 = 28
- 4*8 = 32
- 4*9 = 36
```

I'm confused how to add start and end value.

```js
function printTable(){

    var timesTable =Number(document.getElementById('txtNumber').value);
    for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
    var pTag= document.getElementById('pPrint');
    pTag.innerHTML += (timesTable*i) + "<br/>"
    }
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>JavaScript - Function to Display Table of an entered Number.</h1>
    <p><input type="text" id="txtNumber" placeholder="Enter number"/></p>
    <h1>enter the start value</h1>
    <p><input type="text" id="textNumber" placeholder="Enter number"/></p>
    <h1>enter the end value</h1>
    <p><input type="text" id="teextNumber" placeholder="Enter number"/></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Print Table." onclick='printTable()'/>
    <!--print numbers-->
    <p id="pPrint"></p>
</body>
```

How to add a starting and ending point for multiplication timetable in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then I've add the multiplication function as following:

```js
function printTable(){

    var ps =Number(document.getElementById('txtNumber').value);
    var start =Number(document.getElementById('textNumber').value);
    var end =Number(document.getElementById('teextNumber').value);
    for(var i=start; i<=end; i++){
    var pTag= document.getElementById('pPrint');
    pTag.innerHTML += "- " + (ps) + "*" + (i) + " = " + ps*i + "<br/>"
    }
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>JavaScript - Function to Display Table of an entered Number.</h1>
    <p><input type="text" id="txtNumber" placeholder="Enter number"/></p>
    <h1>enter the start value</h1>
    <p><input type="text" id="textNumber" placeholder="Enter number"/></p>
    <h1>enter the end value</h1>
    <p><input type="text" id="teextNumber" placeholder="Enter number"/></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Print Table." onclick='printTable()'/>
    <!--print numbers-->
    <p id="pPrint"></p>
</body>
```

ps is the starting multiplication number, start is the starting number to times and end the ending number.

Edit: add missing boxes

Comment: I think your code is perfectly fine, but you missed a box under the "end value".

Comment: can you recheck @ninga

Comment: yes, it is working now. thank you for your time! @Mukyuu

Comment: glad to hear that, if you don't mind you could accept the answer :)

Comment: I will, but I don't know how to accept it. I'm new to this website

Comment: I checked marked the v sign but I can't vote for up because I don't have enough reputations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, perhaps you could do the following;

1. Get the starting number via `Number(document.getElementById('textNumber').value)`
2. Get the ending number via `Number(document.getElementById('teextNumber').value)`
3. Use your for loop to start looping from the starting number to the ending number via `for(var i= start; i<= end; i++){`

You should also check that the starting number is less than the ending number to ensure the loop terminates:

```js
function printTable(){
  
  var start = Number(document.getElementById('textNumber').value);
  var end = Number(document.getElementById('teextNumber').value);
  var timesTable =Number(document.getElementById('txtNumber').value);

  // Query document for pTag once, rather than per loop iteration
  var pTag= document.getElementById('pPrint');
  
  // Check that start is less than end, to ensure that the loop 
  // terminates (ie doesn't loop infinitely)
  if(start < end) {
  
    for(var i= start; i<= end; i++){
       
      // Present the multiplication in the required format 
      pTag.innerHTML += ('- ' + i + ' * ' + timesTable + ' = ' + (timesTable*i) + '<br/>')
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<h5>JavaScript - Function to Display Table of an entered Number.</h5>
<p><input type="text" id="txtNumber" placeholder="Enter number"/></p>
<h5>enter the start value</h5>
<p><input type="text" id="textNumber" placeholder="Enter number"/></p>
<h5>enter the end value</h5>
<p><input type="text" id="teextNumber" placeholder="Enter number"/></p>
<p><input type="button" value="Print Table." onclick='printTable()'/>

<p id="pPrint"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add starting point and ending point to for loop as below:

---

```
function printTable(){
    var timesTable =Number(document.getElementById('txtNumber').value);
    var start = document.getElementById("textNumber").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("teextNumber").value;

    for(var i=start; i<=end; i++){
    var pTag= document.getElementById('pPrint');
    pTag.innerHTML += (timesTable*i) + "<br/>"
 }
```

}